# php __destruct method codeingiter 3 persist object to session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have the following vanilla php class in my project in codeigntier. The class holds some data and persists it to session on `__destruct`

```
class PHPPOSCart
{
    public $this->foo = 'bar';
    public  $this->bar = 'foo';
    //Saves the state of the cart to session
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->session->set_userdata('cart', serialize($this));
    }
}
```

Implement (1st request)

```
$cart = new PHPPOSCartRecv();
$cart->bar = 'foo!!!';
```

2nd request:

```
$cart = unserialize($this->CI->session->userdata('cart'));
echo $cart->bar; //This is now foo!!!
```

it works as expected.

I get nervous reading information about `__destruct` in the php manual the order is not known and am worried that in same setups it won't persist at the right time. Program needs to run in many environments >=php 5.3.7 on many types of web servers. I like the idea of being able to have class responsible for persisting data but worry it might not work as expected. I have tested on php 5.4,5.6 and 7.1 without issue.

Is there a better way to do this or am I worried about nothing?

Comment: I believe your code looks safe to any PHP version 5+. I use similar technique in a similar way e.g. destructors collecting/writing to DB or session on various projects & environments (usually PHP 5.5+, centos, windows, sometime IIS). AFAIK, mechanism has not changed since years, only in PHP7 has been added new option `allowed_classes` for the sake of security.